# Interpolating a 4x4 model view matrix is very slow for Android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, math, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I´m developing my own 3d engine for a college project in java, for Android. I can see a very high drop frame rate when executing my program. Profiling the app I can see that almost a 20% of the CPU time is being consumed by my interpolate matrix algorithm. Can you take a look and try to find any time consuming call that can be fixed to work faster ?

This is the code of the matrix interpolation:

```
public static float[] InterpolateMatrix(float timeInAnimation,
                                            float[] timeInputValues, float[][] outputValues, InterpolationType type) {

    float[] result = null;
    if ((timeInputValues != null )&&(outputValues != null)&&(type != null)){
        if (type == InterpolationType.LINEAR){
            float[] trans_matVals1 = outputValues[0];
            float[] trans_matVals2 = outputValues[1];

            // vamos a probar a transponerlo por eso de que las matrices collada se guardan transpuestas
            float[] matVals1 = new float[16];
            float[] matVals2 = new float[16];
            Matrix.transposeM(matVals1,0,trans_matVals1,0);
            Matrix.transposeM(matVals2,0,trans_matVals2,0);

            float[] rotScalMat1 = new float[3*3];
            rotScalMat1[0] = matVals1[0];
            rotScalMat1[1] = matVals1[1];
            rotScalMat1[2] = matVals1[2];
            //                              3
            rotScalMat1[3] = matVals1[4];
            rotScalMat1[4] = matVals1[5];
            rotScalMat1[5] = matVals1[6];
            //                              7
            rotScalMat1[6] = matVals1[8];
            rotScalMat1[7] = matVals1[9];
            rotScalMat1[8] = matVals1[10];


            float[] rotScalMat2 = new float[3*3];
            rotScalMat2[0] = matVals2[0];
            rotScalMat2[1] = matVals2[1];
            rotScalMat2[2] = matVals2[2];
            //                              3
            rotScalMat2[3] = matVals2[4];
            rotScalMat2[4] = matVals2[5];
            rotScalMat2[5] = matVals2[6];
            //                              7
            rotScalMat2[6] = matVals2[8];
            rotScalMat2[7] = matVals2[9];
            rotScalMat2[8] = matVals2[10];
            //                              11
            // sacamos vectores de translaci�n
            float[] vecTrans1 = new float[3];
            vecTrans1[0] = matVals1[12];
            vecTrans1[1] = matVals1[13];
            vecTrans1[2] = matVals1[14];

            float[] vecTrans2 = new float[3];
            vecTrans2[0] = matVals2[12];
            vecTrans2[1] = matVals2[13];
            vecTrans2[2] = matVals2[14];

            float[][] outputTranslateVectors = new float[2][];
            outputTranslateVectors[0] = vecTrans1;
            outputTranslateVectors[1] = vecTrans2;

            float[] interpolatedTransVector = CHelperFunctions.InterpolateVector(timeInAnimation, timeInputValues, outputTranslateVectors, type);

            // sacamos vector de escalada
            Vector3D vS1x = new Vector3D(rotScalMat1[0],rotScalMat1[1],rotScalMat1[2]);
            Vector3D vS1y = new Vector3D(rotScalMat1[3],rotScalMat1[4],rotScalMat1[5]);
            Vector3D vS1z = new Vector3D(rotScalMat1[6],rotScalMat1[7],rotScalMat1[8]);

            Vector3D vS2x = new Vector3D(rotScalMat2[0],rotScalMat2[1],rotScalMat2[2]);
            Vector3D vS2y = new Vector3D(rotScalMat2[3],rotScalMat2[4],rotScalMat2[5]);
            Vector3D vS2z = new Vector3D(rotScalMat2[6],rotScalMat2[7],rotScalMat2[8]);

            float[] scale1 = new float[3];
            scale1[0] = vS1x.lenght();
            scale1[1] = vS1y.lenght();
            scale1[2] = vS1z.lenght();

            float[] scale2 = new float[3];
            scale2[0] = vS2x.lenght();
            scale2[1] = vS2y.lenght();
            scale2[2] = vS2z.lenght();

            float[][] outputScaleVectors = new float[2][];
            outputScaleVectors[0] = scale1;
            outputScaleVectors[1] = scale2;


            //timeInAnimation me está dando un número negativo. no es posible.

            float[] interpolatedScaleVector = CHelperFunctions.InterpolateVector(timeInAnimation, timeInputValues, outputScaleVectors, type);

            float[] identityMatrix = new float[16];
            Matrix.setIdentityM(identityMatrix, 0);

            float[] scaleMatrix1 = new float[16];
            Matrix.scaleM(scaleMatrix1, 0, identityMatrix, 0, scale1[0], scale1[1], scale1[2]);

            float[] scaleMatrix2 = new float[16];
            Matrix.scaleM(scaleMatrix2, 0, identityMatrix, 0, scale2[0], scale2[1], scale2[2]);

            float[] interpolatedScaleMatrix = new float[16];

            Matrix.scaleM(interpolatedScaleMatrix, 0, identityMatrix, 0, interpolatedScaleVector[0], interpolatedScaleVector[1], interpolatedScaleVector[2]);

            /*
             * Matriz original = Matriz Scale * Matriz Rotate (o viceversa), por lo que:
             * M.Rotate = M.Scale^-1 * Matriz original
             */

            float[] invScaleMat1 = new float[16];
            float[] invScaleMat2 = new float[16];

            Matrix.invertM(invScaleMat1, 0, scaleMatrix1, 0);
            Matrix.invertM(invScaleMat2, 0, scaleMatrix2, 0);

            float[] rotMat1 = new float[16];
            float[] rotMat2 = new float[16];

            float[] rotScaleMat1 = new float[16];
            System.arraycopy(matVals1, 0, rotScaleMat1, 0, matVals1.length);
            rotScaleMat1[12] = 0;
            rotScaleMat1[13] = 0;
            rotScaleMat1[14] = 0;
            rotScaleMat1[15] = 0;

            float[] rotScaleMat2 = new float[16];
            System.arraycopy(matVals2, 0, rotScaleMat2, 0, matVals2.length);
            rotScaleMat2[12] = 0;
            rotScaleMat2[13] = 0;
            rotScaleMat2[14] = 0;
            rotScaleMat2[15] = 0;


            // Recordemos f�rmula: M.Rotate = M.Scale^-1 * Matriz original
            //rootMat1 = invScaleMat1 * rotScaleMat1;  eliminando la translaci�n de la matriz
            Matrix.multiplyMM(rotMat1, 0, invScaleMat1, 0, rotScaleMat1, 0);

            Matrix.multiplyMM(rotMat2, 0, invScaleMat2, 0, rotScaleMat2, 0);

            /* MATRIX VIENE DE COLLADA ---> TRANSPOSED = TRUE */
/*
lo de escalar la matriz puede estar mal
                    pero a partir de este punto está segurisimo mal, empezando porque
                    la matriz ya se ha transpuesto (para calcular el vector translate interpolado),
                    con lo cual transposed debería valer false;


            boolean transposed = true;
*/
            boolean transposed = false;
            CMatrix rotCMat1 = new CMatrix(null,rotMat1,transposed); //sid, float array

            CMatrix rotCMat2 = new CMatrix(null,rotMat2,transposed); //sid, float array

            Quaternion q1 = Quaternion.GetQuaternionFromRotationMatrix(rotCMat1);

            Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.GetQuaternionFromRotationMatrix(rotCMat2);

            Quaternion interpolatedQuaternion = null;

            if (( timeInAnimation >= 0 ) && (timeInAnimation < timeInputValues[1])){
                float intervalTime = timeInputValues[1] - timeInputValues[0];
                float currentIntervalTime;
                /* Si es negativo intervalTime es porque hemos superado el tiempo m�ximo de la animaci�n
                 * y se ha invertido el intervalo a interpolar para interpolar desde el �ltimo valor
                 * al primero - tiempo transcurrido desde el segundo cero
                 */
                if (intervalTime < 0){
                    /* timeInputValues[1] es este caso el valor mayor del intervalo a animar,
                     * pues timeInputValues[0] que es el m�ximo, es considerado cero 
                     * al ser la animaci�n ejecutada de forma circular
                     */



                    intervalTime = timeInputValues[1] - 0;
                    currentIntervalTime = timeInAnimation - 0;
                }
                else {
                    currentIntervalTime = timeInAnimation - timeInputValues[0] ;
                }


                /* Percentage ir� de cero a uno */
                float percentage = (currentIntervalTime/intervalTime)/* * 100*/;

                interpolatedQuaternion = Quaternion.slerp(q1, q2, percentage);


            }
            else {
                throw new RuntimeException("CHelperFunctions.InterpolateMatrix: NO SE HA NORMALIZADO EL TIEMPO DE CERO A UNO!!!");
            }

            float[] equivalentInterpolatedRotationMatrix = interpolatedQuaternion.getEquivalentRotationMatrix();

            float[] scaleXrotateMat = new float[16];

            Matrix.multiplyMM(scaleXrotateMat, 0, interpolatedScaleMatrix, 0, equivalentInterpolatedRotationMatrix, 0);

            result = new float[16];
            System.arraycopy(scaleXrotateMat, 0, result, 0, scaleXrotateMat.length);

            result[12] = interpolatedTransVector[0];
            result[13] = interpolatedTransVector[1];
            result[14] = interpolatedTransVector[2];
            result[15] = 1.0f;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And these are the auxiliar functions used:

```
public static float[] InterpolateVector(float timeInAnimation, float[] timeInputValues, float[][] outputValues,
                                                                                            InterpolationType type) {


    float result[] = null;

    if ((timeInputValues != null) &&(timeInputValues.length == 2)
                            && (outputValues != null) && (outputValues.length == 2) && (type != null)){

        float[] outputValues1 = outputValues[0];
        float[] outputValues2 = outputValues[1];


        /*
        if (timeInputValues[0] == timeInputValues[1]){
            Log.e("prueba", "prueba");
        }
        */


        int outputSize = outputValues1.length;
        // if (type == InterpolationType.LINEAR){
            if (( timeInAnimation >= 0 ) && (timeInAnimation <= timeInputValues[1])){
                result = new float[outputSize];
                for (int index = 0; index < outputSize; index++){
                    float[][] outputToPass = new float[2][1];
                    outputToPass[0][0] = outputValues1[index];
                    outputToPass[1][0] = outputValues2[index];
                    result[index] = CHelperFunctions.InterpolateValue(timeInAnimation, timeInputValues, outputToPass, type);
                }
            }
        // }


    }
    //else {
    //    Log.e("CHelperFunctions", "codigo de depuración");
    //}
    return result;
}

public static float InterpolateValue(float timeInAnimation, float[] timeInputValues, 
                                        float[][] outputValues, InterpolationType type) {

    float result = -1.0f;

    if ((timeInputValues != null) &&(timeInputValues.length == 2)
                            && (outputValues != null) && (outputValues.length == 2) && (type != null)){

        if (type == InterpolationType.LINEAR){
            if (( timeInAnimation >= 0 ) && (timeInAnimation < timeInputValues[1])){



                float intervalTime = timeInputValues[1] - timeInputValues[0];
                float currentIntervalTime;
                /* Si es negativo intervalTime es porque hemos superado el tiempo m�ximo de la animaci�n
                 * y se ha invertido el intervalo a interpolar para interpolar desde el �ltimo valor
                 * al primero - tiempo transcurrido desde el segundo cero
                 */
                if (intervalTime < 0){
                    /* timeInputValues[1] es este caso el valor mayor del intervalo a animar,
                     * pues timeInputValues[0] que es el m�ximo, es considerado cero 
                     * al ser la animaci�n ejecutada de forma circular
                     */
                    intervalTime = timeInputValues[1] - 0;
                    currentIntervalTime = timeInAnimation - 0;
                }
                else {
                    currentIntervalTime = timeInAnimation - timeInputValues[0] ;
                }


                /*
                float intervalTime = timeInputValues[1] - timeInputValues[0];
                float currentIntervalTime = timeInputValues[0] - timeInAnimation;
                */
                /* Percentage ir� de cero a uno */
                float percentage = (currentIntervalTime/intervalTime)/* * 100*/;

                float outputValue1 = outputValues[0][0];
                float outputValue2 = outputValues[1][0];


                /* FROM WAZIN TUTORIAL:
                 * float Interpolate( float a_Value1, float a_Value2, float a_T)
                    {
                        return ((a_Value2 * a_T) + ((1 - a_T) * a_Value1));
                    }   
                 */
                result = ((outputValue2 * percentage) + ((1 - percentage)*outputValue1));

            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static Quaternion GetQuaternionFromRotationMatrix(CMatrix mat){
    /*
    1-descomponer la matrix en matriz de rotaci�n y matriz de escalado
    2-obtener quaternion de matriz de rotacion segun siguiente web:
        http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm
    3-devolver quaternion

    COMO SE RECOMPONE LA MATRIX:
        Matriz = R*S + T (creo que tb vale scale*rotate)

    */
    if (mat == null) return null;

    float[] associatedArray = mat.GetTransposedMatrixArray();
    float[] rotScalMat = new float[3*3];
    rotScalMat[0] = associatedArray[0];
    rotScalMat[1] = associatedArray[1];
    rotScalMat[2] = associatedArray[2];
    //                              3
    rotScalMat[3] = associatedArray[4];
    rotScalMat[4] = associatedArray[5];
    rotScalMat[5] = associatedArray[6];
    //                              7
    rotScalMat[6] = associatedArray[8];
    rotScalMat[7] = associatedArray[9];
    rotScalMat[8] = associatedArray[10];
    /*
     * 
    float tr = m00 + m11 + m22

    if (tr > 0) { 
        float S = sqrt(tr+1.0) * 2; // S=4*qw 
        qw = 0.25 * S;
        qx = (m21 - m12) / S;
        qy = (m02 - m20) / S; 
        qz = (m10 - m01) / S; 
    } 
    else if ((m00 > m11)&(m00 > m22)) { 
        float S = sqrt(1.0 + m00 - m11 - m22) * 2; // S=4*qx 
        qw = (m21 - m12) / S;
        qx = 0.25 * S;
        qy = (m01 + m10) / S; 
        qz = (m02 + m20) / S; 
    } 
    else if (m11 > m22) { 
        float S = sqrt(1.0 + m11 - m00 - m22) * 2; // S=4*qy
        qw = (m02 - m20) / S;
        qx = (m01 + m10) / S; 
        qy = 0.25 * S;
        qz = (m12 + m21) / S; 
    } 
    else { 
        float S = sqrt(1.0 + m22 - m00 - m11) * 2; // S=4*qz
        qw = (m10 - m01) / S;
        qx = (m02 + m20) / S;
        qy = (m12 + m21) / S;
        qz = 0.25 * S;
    }

     */

    float qw=-1, qx=-1, qy=-1, qz=-1;

    float tr = rotScalMat[0] + rotScalMat[4] + rotScalMat[8];

    if (tr > 0) { 
        float S = (float) (Math.sqrt(tr+1.0) * 2); // S=4*qw 
        qw = 0.25f * S;
        qx = (rotScalMat[7] - rotScalMat[5]) / S;
        qy = (rotScalMat[2] - rotScalMat[6]) / S; 
        qz = (rotScalMat[3] - rotScalMat[1]) / S; 
    } 
    else if ((rotScalMat[0] > rotScalMat[4])&&(rotScalMat[0] > rotScalMat[8])) { 
        float S = (float) (Math.sqrt(1.0 + rotScalMat[0] - rotScalMat[4] - rotScalMat[8]) * 2); // S=4*qx 
        qw = (rotScalMat[7] - rotScalMat[5]) / S;
        qx = 0.25f * S;
        qy = (rotScalMat[1] + rotScalMat[3]) / S; 
        qz = (rotScalMat[2] + rotScalMat[6]) / S; 
    } 
    else if (rotScalMat[4] > rotScalMat[8]) { 
        float S = (float) (Math.sqrt(1.0 + rotScalMat[4] - rotScalMat[0] - rotScalMat[8]) * 2); // S=4*qy
        qw = (rotScalMat[2] - rotScalMat[6]) / S;
        qx = (rotScalMat[1] + rotScalMat[3]) / S; 
        qy = 0.25f * S;
        qz = (rotScalMat[5] + rotScalMat[7]) / S; 
    } 
    else { 
        float S = (float) (Math.sqrt(1.0 + rotScalMat[8] - rotScalMat[0] - rotScalMat[4]) * 2); // S=4*qz
        qw = (rotScalMat[3] - rotScalMat[1]) / S;
        qx = (rotScalMat[2] + rotScalMat[6]) / S;
        qy = (rotScalMat[5] + rotScalMat[7]) / S;
        qz = 0.25f * S;
    }
    return new Quaternion(qx,qy,qz,qw);
}
```

These methods are call a lot of times each frame, so a little performance penality can affect so much the final app performance.

I suspect of the multiple array creation for allocating the vectors, matrices and quaternios.

Can you sugest any better alternative in any of these methods?

EDIT:
This is the slerp method I use to interpolate quaternions:

```
//! spherical linear interpolation
public static Quaternion slerp(Quaternion q1, 
        Quaternion q2, float t) 
{
    Quaternion q3;
    float dot = q1.dotProduct(q2);

    /*  dot = cos(theta)
        if (dot < 0), q1 and q2 are more than 90 degrees apart,
        so we can invert one to reduce spinning */
    if (dot < 0)
    {
        dot = -dot;
        q3 = q2.mulScalar(-1.0f);
    } else q3 = new Quaternion(q2.x,q2.y,q2.z,q2.w);

    if (dot < 0.95f)
    {
        float angle = (float)Math.acos((double)dot);
        Quaternion quatFat1 = q1.mulScalar((float)Math.sin(angle*(1-t)));
        Quaternion auxQuatFat2 = q3.mulScalar((float)Math.sin(angle*t));
        Quaternion quatFat2 = auxQuatFat2.mulScalar((float)(1.0f/Math.sin(angle)));

        Quaternion result = quatFat1.sum(quatFat2);
        // return (q1*sinf(angle*(1-t)) + q3*sinf(angle*t))/sinf(angle);
        return result;

    } else // if the angle is small, use linear interpolation                               
        return Quaternion.lerp(q1,q3,t);        
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of small temporary buffers (vectors, matrices...) in those functions, even inside inner loops, maybe all those allocations (and garbage collector tasks) wastes some time.  Can you use some static buffers in place of dynamic ones?

Comment: Thanks @marekb . I´m going to try to save some time in the way you suggest